# How to makes tuples from a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a this specific nested list :

```
 paths = [['s', 'a', 'b', 't'], ['s', 'c', 'd', 't'], ['s', 'c', 'e']
```

and i want to take tuples of 2 in each nested list , for example i want as output this:

```
 ['s', 'a'] , ['a', 'b'] ,['b', 't'] , ['s', 'c'] ,...
```

and so on.
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Your desired output is closest to a list of lists. No tuples involved.

Comment: i forgot to mention that after i split them in 2, i want to check if each tuple is in a dictionary and then do something else

Comment: For your subsequent tasks. First see if you can do them yourself. If you can't, search on SO. If you are still stuck after a few hours, feel free to post *as a separate question*. I have rolled back your update. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
paths = [['s', 'a', 'b', 't'], ['s', 'c', 'd', 't'], ['s', 'c', 'e']]

res = []
for item in paths:
    for i in range(len(item) - 1):
        x = []
        x.append(item[i])
        x.append(item[i+1])
        res.append(x)
print res
```

output:

```
[['s', 'a'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 't'], ['s', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], ['d', 't'], ['s', 'c'], ['c', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version with no imported modules using a list comprehension:

```
paths = [['s', 'a', 'b', 't'], ['s', 'c', 'd', 't'], ['s', 'c', 'e']]

res = [[j[i], j[i+1]] for j in paths for i in range(len(j)-1)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['s', 'a'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 't'], ['s', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], ['d', 't'], ['s', 'c'], ['c', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a nested list comprehension with `zip`:

```
paths = [['s', 'a', 'b', 't'], ['s', 'c', 'd', 't']]

res = [[i, j] for x in paths for i, j in zip(x, x[1:])]
```

Result:

```
[['s', 'a'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 't'], ['s', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], ['d', 't']]
```